# Как полность скопировать страницу в вордпрессе?

Tags: python, wordpress

У меня есть программа для автопоста вордпресс с помощью селениума. Я копорию html код, который мне надо, с других сайтов к примеру div class='st'(внутри текст и картинки). Всё это я вставляю в HTML блок. Но есть проблема - hTML файлы совпадают, но CSS файлы нет. Тоесть картинки и текст правильные, но расположение нет. Как можно это решить?

Comment: Ликбез: сss делается не для каждой страницы свой, а один-два для сразу для всего сайта, возможно для типов страниц. В любой системе, вне зависимости от движка. Посему затея с копипастом css - путь в бездну. И не только пото выше сказанным причинам. а и потому что в итоге будет жопа на фронте. Копипасть только контент.

Comment: но он не корректно отображается, это не исправить?

Comment: Исправить. И вариантов масса в зависимости от конкретики. Но телепатически это могут делать экстрасенсы. Я таких не знаю.